# Can we discuss topical news on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, news

Can we discuss recent developments in the world of IT on Super User, recent programming news on Stack Overflow, etc.?

I can see reasons why this would be great. We have great informed communities and discussions would be in-depth and insightful. I think people would learn quite a lot, and the quality would be better than the usual found on forums.

On the other hand, we are at Q&A sites, and even with community wiki I imagine this could cause some issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Super User is not a discussion site, it is also a Q&A site.

Comment: This is, while accurate, unhelpful.

Answer (score 14):

**Rule of thumb**: *If the word "discussion" pops into your head, it is generally not going to work well under a Q&A system.*

Comment: My thumbs refuse to live under your rules, man!

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow and Super User both have associated [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) [sites](http://chat.superuser.com). Most other sites have a chat room off of the [master Stack Exchange Chat site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). That's a much better medium for the kind of discussion you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Following a conversation in the format provided for Q & A would be so severely confusing that in order to make that work, a new view would be required. Though, like Joel said, there are already other ways to discuss things, so it would quite possibly be wasted effort.