# Does Stack Exchange need subsites for news submission?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Stack Exchange successfully expanded beyond programming questions. It preserved high standards of discussion even in opinionated and ideological topics, such as politics and economics. There's a great community behind these achievements.

I'm sure this great community not only asks and answers questions, but also read news. And these news must be more reliable and objective that elsewhere. Just for the same reasons why questions and answers on Stack Exchange are more reliable and objective.

But there's no place on Stack Exchange to share these news. You can, of course, submit links elsewhere, but those places lack the culture of Stack Exchange. So, it doesn't work well.

Should Stack Exchange have its own news submission subsites, in addition to topical Q&A subsites? Something like `news.stats.stackexchange.com` for stats.SE, along with `meta.stats.stackexchange.com` and `chat.stackexchange.com`?

Technically, submission, commenting, and voting look exactly the same in the news submission process, as they do in Q&A. But news naturally require a separate listing.

And yes, by "news" I mean any link you'd like to share. Not only the recent stuff, but older publications as well.

### Why not chat or blogs

After being sent to a duplicate [Can we discuss topical news on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/can-we-discuss-topical-news-on-se-sites) (which I don't consider as such because it suggests discussing news in the same listings with questions—I don't support that), I'd clarify a bit.

So, yes, there're tricks to add news right now (among suggested here: chats, blogs, masking your news as questions), but they are inefficient ways to manage news. From a news submission website, you'd expect two things: (1) inflow of good links, (2) voting and ranking on these links. Chats, blogs, and Q&A don't meet these requirements.

As an example, Stack Exchange is successful not because it forced users to use tricks on good old message boards, which don't suit Q&A needs, but because it designed an efficient way to manage Q&As. Apparently, this design is not far from an optimal design of a news submission service.

Objections like "I wouldn't use such a service" are fine here, but my suggestion is not about finding broken ways to submit links to Stack Exchange.

Comment: How do you "answer" news?

Comment: Set up a chat room to share whatever links you feel like sharing, this doesn't fit at all with the purpose of SE sites.

Comment: @Doorknob Well, what if instead "add answer" the button will say "add comment"?

Comment: Then what are (actual) comments for? (Also, the strict Q&A format does *not* fit well with comment-answers.)

Comment: @Mat Chats aren't designed to rank submitted news. Compare news.ycombinator.com to any chat and tell which of the two you'll check for news.

Comment: if you see a news story you really want to share then just think about a way you can include it in a question you have

Comment: This looks like a whole mask to find your new reddit

Comment: @random Why "duplicate"?

Comment: You still want to use SE with its user base and voting tools to discuss news, much like how reddit has, but we don't discuss news and are focussed on Q&A

Answer (score 2):

Currently, such mechanisms are provided via:

- Featured meta posts, if the changes are related to the change in features in the system of stacks (i.e. Stack Exchange v2.0-powered sites).
- Otherwise, blog posts. Those are typically filled with the other sort of news, i.e. how some events ended, survey results maybe, or announcements of new employees, or, as it happened recently the blog itself got updated. That's with the blog.stackexchange.com.

As for the topics not related to Stack Exchange: [some sites have their own blogs](https://stackexchange.com/blogs), which discuss the topics which don't fit Q&A system, but fit the site's topic (for example, [one of the posts on the TeX Community blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/03/latex-beginners-guide-available-for-download-today/)). However since some time ago, the new blogs are no longer created.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The news wouldn't be related to Stack Exchange, but to the subject of each site.

Comment: @ani aah, then the last paragraph of my answer?